# VS code autoformat python file with autopep8 not working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatting

So I am trying to get an auto format setup for Python files with autopep8 in VS code I tried to use the "format document with" option to set the default formatter to autopep8 however when I try to use the "format document" option nothing happens and when I try to use the "format selection" option it doesn't work and I get this message:

"Extension 'autopep8' is configured as formatter but it cannot format 'python'-files"

I checked the settings.json in the .vscode file in my virtual environment and I have this:

```
{
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8"
    },
    "python.formatting.provider": "none",
}
```

this matches the settings found in this vs code tutorial [text](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/formatting) I also tried to comment out the python.formatting.provider line but nothing changed. Lastly I also checked the user settings.json and it also matches the tutorial I linked previously:

```
{
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8"
    }
}
```

not sure what else to try and whats going wrong here

Comment: Can you show your specific questions and examples? 
Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Comment: I had a similar problem where VSCode seemed to do nothing, but following [@Варков Эмир](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22315197/%d0%92%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%ad%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80)'s lead, I opened the logs and noticed an error message saying that my Python interpreter version (3.7) was not supported. After switching to a newer version (3.9) autopep8 started working again. You can open the logs by opening the command palette, then typing "Developer: Show Logs" and then scroll until you find "autopep8".

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue, and after examining the logs, I noticed an error mentioned in this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-autopep8/issues/113)e. They reported that this problem should be fixed in the pre-release version. So, what worked for me was installing the pre-release version of the extension.

Comment: Same its not working even after switching to pre-release version

Comment: @SathishKumar it is not working for me as well. Now I am forced to use black instead of autopep as formatter.